# I had created a external library when I integrated that library in two apps, 2nd app is not installing

Tags: android

I had created a external library when I integrated that library in two apps when installing 2nd app I am getting "the package conflicts with an existing package by the same name" issue for proguard apps.

while the integrated apps are debug then both apps are installing in same device.

while the integrated apps are release then both apps are not installing in same device getting issue like "the package conflicts with an existing package by the same name".

Comment: Please check the package names of both the apps and library. There could be same package name usage issue.

Comment: no, the both apps package names are different. If I exclude the library then both apps are installing in same device. If I included the library then I am getting a issue. I can't understand why external library impacts on apps.

Comment: Are you using '<provider ...> ... </provider>' functionality in your AndroidManifest of Lib and AppS ?

Comment: I am not using any <provider ...> ... </provider> in library, but using <receiver ...> ... </receiver> in library manifest file

Comment: Can you post the code of <receiver> which is used in your lib ...

Comment: <receiver
    android:name="com.truepush.sdk.network.FirebaseDataReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name="com.truepush.sdk.NotificationEventReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"/>

Comment: It seems, android:name of <receiver> is same ( of library ) which is derived in both the apps. You may refer google developer document link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element -- I am not sure, but you may try name start with "dot" for eg. like ".sdk.FirebaseDataReceiver" and ".sdk.NotificationEventReceiver" for both receivers. As per help document, system will append the app package before it. So the name will become unique. Which may solve your issue.

Comment: Still I am getting the same issue

Comment: See my updated answer. Uninstall all apps and lib app from your test device. Clean, Build, Generate Signed apk and then try installing apps again in device.

Comment: Hi SHS, Thanks for your support. Finally I got a solution.

Comment: Great, if you have got the solution with below answer, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Replace
<permission
    android:name="com.truepush.sdk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.truepush.sdk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

to
<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

And in receiver’s intent-filter:

replace
<category android:name="com.truepush.sdk"/>

to
<category android:name="${applicationId}"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the code for Provider in AndroidManifest file of Lib, then please remove it from lib. Move it to Apps' AndroidManifest file. The following should be unique in AndroidManifest of both Apps.

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="your unique app package name"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths_public" />
    </provider>
```

The XML file will be in app resource xml folder as under

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
        <external-path
            name="external_files"
            path="." />
        <root-path
            name="external_files"
            path="/storage/" />
    </paths>
```

This is also one of the cause for 'package conflicts'

In the case of AndroidManifest of Library, we need to ensure android:name should start with 'dot' for eg. ".sdk.network.FirebaseDataReceiver". The same apply to 'service android:name ...' also.

I am adding example of 'Receiver' in AndroidManifest file.

```
    <receiver android:name=".sdk.network.FirebaseDataReceiver" 
        android:exported="false" 
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> '
        <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```